# MAMP Pro - is there a way to sort virtual hosts?

Tags: mamp, virtualhost, mamp-pro

I have many Virtual Hosts configured in MAMP Pro.

In the Hosts Table, they are listed in the order in which they were created, which is not very convenient.

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to sort them alphabetically for example?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately for you, you're on MAMP PRO 4, so you can click on the column header 'Name' to sort. A-Z, Z-A

In MAMP PRO 5 they have removed the column headers altogether, so you are stuck with the order in which they were created, which is frustrating (Even though you can drag and drop them into a different order, (I spent ages manually rearranging my hosts alphabetically) but it doesn't save the ordering, so next time you open MAMP, it's back to the order in which they were created)

Having lots of offline hosts makes it really difficult to pick one out at a glance, so I wish they'd re-introduce the column headers, like in MAMP PRO 4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it does not solve my problem.
I have MAMP PRO V5, the screenshot was here just to illustrate the question but it's not my MAMP.

In V5 you can drag and drop the Virtual Hosts but when you close then reopen the application you loose all your changes. That's stupid but it's the way it works.